# I believe GCC is producing incorrect machine code

Tags: gcc, x86

I am trying to compile this dead simple program:

```
int print(int x, int y)
{
    return x * y;
}

int main()
{
    return print(8, 7);
}
```

with this command: `gcc -c -nostdinc -m32 -masm=intel main.c -O0`

The file produced (`main.o`) has the following object dump:

```
$ objdump -d main.o                             

main.o:     file format elf32-i386


Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <print>:
   0:   55                      push   %ebp
   1:   89 e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp
   3:   e8 fc ff ff ff          call   4 <print+0x4>
   8:   05 01 00 00 00          add    $0x1,%eax
   d:   8b 45 08                mov    0x8(%ebp),%eax
  10:   0f af 45 0c             imul   0xc(%ebp),%eax
  14:   5d                      pop    %ebp
  15:   c3                      ret    

00000016 <main>:
  16:   55                      push   %ebp
  17:   89 e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp
  19:   e8 fc ff ff ff          call   1a <main+0x4>
  1e:   05 01 00 00 00          add    $0x1,%eax
  23:   6a 07                   push   $0x7
  25:   6a 08                   push   $0x8
  27:   e8 fc ff ff ff          call   28 <main+0x12>
  2c:   83 c4 08                add    $0x8,%esp
  2f:   c9                      leave  
  30:   c3                      ret    

Disassembly of section .text.__x86.get_pc_thunk.ax:

00000000 <__x86.get_pc_thunk.ax>:
   0:   8b 04 24                mov    (%esp),%eax
   3:   c3                      ret
```

If I understand correctly, this line
`27:   e8 fc ff ff ff          call   28 <main+0x12>` represents the call to `print`. However, the offset given is -4, which results in jumping to address 28. But there isn't even an instruction at that offset. The code does run however. But I have the feeling this machine code isn't quite right. (Also, why is there a `call` instruction in the print function, if the print function doesn't even call anything?)

Comment: I suggest using [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/M4_g8b) for looking at stuff like this.

Comment: The calls are to `get_pc_thunk` (try -S option on your compile to see some symbols with the assembly). Some info here: [How does the x86 instruction call 135b<__x86.get_pc_thunk.ax> work?](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/20826/how-does-the-x86-instruction-call-135b-x86-get-pc-thunk-ax-work).

Comment: Nothing wrong with the output. You are disassembling an object file and looking at entries that have not been relocated. Use `objdump -dr main.o` to see the instructions that require relocation by the linker or the dynamic loader at runtime. Alternatively make an executable and dump that.

Answer (score 1):

You compiled with `-c`, thus the output is an object file. It still contains placeholders for symbols and such that will be resolved / patched by the linker. As mentioned, use objdump with flag `-r` added  which will show symbol name for the reloc(s). Before linking, the bits in the opcode are 0, thus the call target points to the address as shown by objdump.

Comment: The relative displacements are actually `-4`, the distance between the start of the `rel32` (which might be what the relocation entry uses) vs. the end of the instruction (which the machine code jump is relative to.)